# winter hammock camping

Tags: winter-camping, hammock, down

What's the warmest underquilt I can buy for an asymmetric 1 man camping hammock? My hammock is the Hennessy expedition. I'm thinking of the warbonnet wookie (Scandinavian) but that is custom built for the warbonnet blackbird hammock. Has anyone tried attaching it to other hammocks? Does it have lateral straps that can be clipped?

Comment: I would think that any kind of quilt underneath you would crush and thus lose whatever its rating is.  A sturdy foam or inflatable mattress seems better.

Comment: Hammock underquilts hang underneath the hammock, so you don't crush them. You can also use a mattress like in a tent. Which version you go for is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3):

Well after more research I think the warmest hammock underquilt available is the Revolt v2 from enlightened equipment. The rating goes down to -10F...

I hope that helps someone!